# Windows Batch: fetch first occurrence in a variable listing

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am working on a Windows 7 batch command file (drv.bat) that attempts to map a drive that is already taken. `Net use` would list it as a drive mapping hence `errorlevel` is raised to 2 in this case. Because of that in the following a listing of currently available network drives is displayed.

```
@echo off
setlocal
net use A: \\computername\sharename /persistent:No
ECHO.%ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 for %%p in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if not exist %%p:\nul echo Drive: %%p
...    
endlocal
```

That gives me a listing like so:

```
Drive: F
Drive: G
Drive: J
Drive: M
Drive: R
Drive: S
Drive: T
Drive: X
Drive: Y
Drive: Z
```

My aim is to fetch the first available drive letter. Drive letter availability may vary depending on how many PCs connect to this Workgroup.
So that batch should always assign the first occurence in that listing.
Exactly at this point I am lost.
No worries about the rest until no more drives are available.

Hope someone can help me to get a step further.

Feedback is much appreciated.

---

After a few many hours I got this very bumpy code somewhat working. I much prefer and accept @JosefZ answer, as I find his version a very elegant solution meeting dot-on all my needs - thanks.

```
@echo off
net use B: \\OQO-PC\OQO-SYSTEM /persistent:No
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto end
::rem info: Drive G: for CD-ROM removed in list
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET DRVLSTV=
echo [\\OQO-PC\OQO-SYSTEM] 
ECHO -------------------------------------------
FOR %%f IN (A B C D E F H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF not exist %%f:\nul @set DRVLSTV=!DRVLSTV! %%f:
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%d IN ("%DRVLSTV%") DO IF %%d NEQ " " (net use %%d \\OQO-PC\OQO-SYSTEM /persistent:No)
echo Drive got remapped to the first available drive
endlocal
:end
::net use
::pause
```

Comment: Making one step back... are `popd` and `pushd` of any help?

Comment: Hm, nice thought, but I don't see how to use tat in this case.

Comment: First available drive letter in your example is `Z:`, as network drive units are assigned in reverse order. Thus a line like `pushd \\server\foo & cd & popd` could do the job.

Comment: If you just want to get `Drive: F` (in your example), you need to modify your `IF` statement like this: `if not exist %%p:\nul (echo Drive: %%p && goto :eof)`, then add `:eof` at the very end of the batch file.

Comment: @SalvoF: The :eof might be implied, so no need to add to end of batch file, according to http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem get list of disk letters in use
set "_inUseDisks="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%D in ('
  wmic logicaldisk get caption /value
  ') do (
    for /F "delims=:" %%d in ("%%D") do (
      set "_inUseDisks=!_inUseDisks! %%d"
    )
)
echo Disk letters in use %_inUseDisks%
rem get first available disk letter
set "_available="
for %%p in (C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B) do (
  set "_test=!_inUseDisks:%%p=!"
  if "!_test!"=="%_inUseDisks%" (
    if not defined _available set "_available=%%p"
    rem goto :gotletter
  )
)
:gotletter
if "%_available%"=="" (
  echo No available disk letter
) else (
  rem echo First available disk letter: %_available%:
  echo net use %_available%: \\computername\sharename /persistent:No
)
```

In above script, there the `for` loops are

- `%%D` to retrieve the `caption` value;
- `%%d` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's *[`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)*

- order of letters in `%%p` loop changed;
- operational `net use` is merely displayed for debugging purposes; remove `echo` no sooner than debugged.

**Next resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~D`, `%~d` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`set "_REPLWITH=%_ALLOWED:~-1%"` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: Woha, works like a charm, right out of the box, Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd \\computername\sharename
for /f "delims=" %%u in ('cd') do set av_unit=%%u && echo !av_unit:\ =!
popd
```

`EnableDelayedExpansion` allows variable manipulation inside `for` statement, which only removes backslash and space from drive root dir.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't make it work. It says: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Try changing 2nd line this way: `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: Sorry, still the same (when applied to the code in the question). What is your complete working code?

Comment: That's all I run... smoothly on Windows 7 Pro and Vista Home. How weird

Comment: Alright, I got it working, sorry, my fault. Honestly I have no clue and I cannot comprehend the code or how you got to the last available drive. I trying to figure out how to get the first available drive by following your advice provided earlier. More important to me is: How about mapping several drives 3-4 in one go? I am really impressed about this 3-liner.

Comment: `pushd` does the magic, refer to documentation. Depending on your purpose, it might be enough. Problems arise if you want to force a share to get  always the same drive letter